# the distance from $A$ to the nearest singular matrix is the smallest singular value of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have read (e.g., [here](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0613003) that it is well known that

> the distance from $A$ to the nearest singular matrix is the smallest singular value of $A$

But how can we prove this fact? I tried to start with the SVD of $A$ but am not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: Let $B$ be any singular matrix and $x$ is a unit vector in $\ker B$. Then
$$
\|B-A\|_2\ge\|(B-A)x\|_2=\|-Ax\|_2=\|Ax\|_2\ge\sigma_\min(A).
$$
It remains to show that $\|B-A\|_2=\sigma_\min(A)$ for some matrix $B$. This should be easy.

Comment: @a6623 This result (in its full generality) is known as the [Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Basic_low-rank_approximation_problem)